# On Spotify, can I tell it to 'after the current song finishes, start playing this album'?

Tags: spotify

I use Spotify on Android and the linux application - and so either solution will work because I can control the music from either, but Android preferred.

A common interaction I have is that I'll be listening to a playlist or radio - and then find a song that I really like - and I want to keep listening to that artist. What I can do is click into the album that the song came from - and from there I can press'play', but that will stop the music immediately -which is a bit disruptive.

I'd rather let the song finish, and then continue playing the album.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the Android app, you can long press an album and click `Add to Queue`, which will queue up the entire album after the currently playing song. In the Windows client and, presumably, the Linux client you can right-click an album and select the same option.
[image: Spotify long press screen]